# background image is not displayed online but it is in local

Tags: css, path, background

Can anybody guide me here?

CSS

```
background: url(/img/background_sw_web.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
```

path

http://piscolabis.info/img/

The image:

http://piscolabis.info/licht/img/background_sw_web.jpg

I can't use an absolute path because this domain is for testing

To test: http://piscolabis.info/licht/

The must funny is that in FF with the editCSS plugin when i click on 'edit css' and the sidebar loads the CSS, the image is Shown,

Comment: What is the problem? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the path be like `/licht/img/background_sw_web.jpg` instead?
Or if the file referencing to that image is in the same folder (e.g. the licht folder), just remove the forward slash at the beginning of the path. So it'll be like `img/background_sw_web.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Correct your path: like this:

```
background: url(../img/background_sw_web.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Add: `..` with `/img` like this `../img`

Comment: @Ahsan Rathod I think he already figured that one out by now. Take a look at the page.